# Kubuntu 20.04 automatically adjusts audio volume and it sounds wrong

Tags: sound, kubuntu

**Problem description:**
I have a dualboot with Windows 10 and Kubuntu 20.04 with the latest updates installed. I have speakers connected to the back of the computer via 3.5mm jack and sometimes I connect headphones via the front 3.5mm port. The Kubuntu 20.04 behaves strangely when I play music from headphones. When a song starts playing and its volume is loud, the volume is suddenly decreased. When the song is at an end (usually part with low volume), the volume is increased and it creates a strange repetition of a little bit of the last part of the song. Sound decreasing/increasing happens sometimes during the songs when the part is particularly loud/quiet, too. This happens with many songs. This happens only with headphones (or speakers) connected to the front 3.5mm port, and does not happen when playing music from speakers (or headphones) connected to the back 3.5mm port. This only happens on Kubuntu. On Windows, everything works as it should.

**What I tried:**

- I first noticed the problem when playing music from Spotify, so I tried to reinstall. The sound problem remained.
- I tried to play the same songs on youtube and the problem appears there too at the exact same parts, so it is not a problem with a particular application, but probably system-wide.
- I usually have the application volume set to 100 % and then configure the total volume via device volume (usually around 30 %). When I set the application lower, the system tries to compensate and there is a clear increase in volume. When I set device volume to 100 % and set the app volume to 30 %, then the situation is the same.
- I tried different headphones and the problem still occurs.
- I tried looking into PulseAudio Volume Control, but it didn't have any options except changing volume and setting some latency offset (which didn't do anything as far as I know).
- I tried to look into `alsamixer`, but didn't know what to change.

**Computer configuration:**

```
Power source: Seasonic S12III-650 - 650W
Motherboard: MSI X570-A PRO - AMD X570
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600X 
RAM: HyperX Fury Black 2x8GB
Video card: Gainward GeForce RTX 2060 Ghost OC, 6GB GDDR6
System SSD: Crucial P1, M.2 - 1TB
Data HDD: Seagate BarraCuda, 3,5" - 2TB
```

**Result from `lspci -vv | grep -A7 -i "Audio"`:**

```sh
2d:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 90
        Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
2f:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] X570-A PRO motherboard
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 92
        Memory at f7900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

**Results from `pacmd list-sinks`:**

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 11
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_2f_00.4.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        state: RUNNING
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 9039
        volume: front-left: 16381 /  25% / -36,13 dB,   front-right: 16381 /  25% / -36,13 dB
                balance 0,00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 100,85 ms
        max request: 17 KiB
        max rewind: 17 KiB
        monitor source: 14
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 1
        linked by: 3
        fixed latency: 100,14 ms
        card: 2 <alsa_card.pci-0000_2f_00.4>
        module: 9
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC1220 Analog"
                alsa.id = "ALC1220 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xf7900000 irq 92"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:2f:00.4"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:2f:00.4/sound/card1"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1022"
                device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
                device.product.id = "1487"
                device.product.name = "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller (X570-A PRO motherboard)"
                device.string = "front:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "17664"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "2944"
                device.access_mode = "mmap"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller (X570-A PRO motherboard) Analog Stereo"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:

                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        active port: <analog-output-headphones>
```

Does this happen to anyone else? Does anyone know how to solve this problem

If I should provide some other info, just ask.